# The right way to structure ReactiveSearch components to make search work

Tags: reactjs, reactivesearch

If I have my CRA based ReactiveSearch app structured like this:

```
/src
 /containers
  /search
   -index.js
 /components
  -autocomplete.js
  -results.js
  -navbar.js
```

Where `/containers/search/index.js` contains code like this:

```
<ReactiveBase
    app="someapp"
    credentials="abc123"
    type="sometype"
  >
    <DataSearch
      componentId="q"
      react={{ "and", ["q"] }}
      ...
    />
    <Results />
  <ReactiveBase />
```

And then my own react components (autocomplete.js, results.js) bring in those `ReactiveSearch` components as children as per the needs of my app?

For example, my autocomplete.js would bring in `DataSearch` as a child, my results.js would bring in `ReactiveList` as a child and navbar.js would bring in the same DataSearch as a child?

And that should enable me to create different routes with React Router 4 when ready, right?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? What you are describing is correct and should work.

Comment: @sidi - yes, the problem was that I had multiple ReactiveBase in multiple places instead of just one - that alone solved a lot of the problems that I was having.